# How to show $BB^\dagger$ is hermitian?

Tags: matrices, hermitian-matrices

I have B is a $m\times n$ matrix, with complex entries. Then I want to show that $BB^{\dagger}$ is Hermitian.

In order to satisfy Hermiticity, then $(BB^{\dagger})^{\dagger}$=$BB^{\dagger}$.

I set

$B$ = $\begin{vmatrix}
i & a & c\\
b+i & i & d
\end{vmatrix}$

$B^{\dagger}$ = $\begin{vmatrix}
-i & b-i \\
a & -i \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}$

$B*B^{\dagger} = \begin{vmatrix}
a2+c2−1 & ia+i(b−i)+cd \\
ia+i(b−i)+cd & d2+(b−i)(b+i)−1
\end{vmatrix}$

So then I do:

$(B*B^{\dagger})^{\dagger} = \begin{vmatrix}
a2+c2−1 & -ia+i(b+i)+cd  \\
-ia+i(b+i)+cd  & d2+(b+i)(b-i)−1
\end{vmatrix}$

Is this all?

Comment: Did you used $\dagger$ as Hermitian adjoint?

Comment: I spotted at least one missing sign in your work. Ignoring errors, each of the above square matrices is Hermitian. They aren’t the same matrix though, judging by size alone.

Comment: Hermitian does NOT mean $BB^{\dagger}$=$B^{\dagger}B$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks! Corrected

Comment: A matrix satisfying the condition $A^*A = AA^*$ is called normal, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be misunderstood the defenition of Hermitian matrix. It is not $BB^\star=B^\star B$, but $B=B^\star$.

You can use this three properties, are valid for all matrices: $A^\star=\bar{A}^T, \bar{A}^T=\bar{A^T}, (AB)^\star=B^\star A^\star$. ($\star$ is Hermitian adjoint operator.)

Then...

$$(BB^\star)^\star=(B^\star)^\star B^\star=\bar{(\bar{B^T})}^T B^\star=(B^T)^T B^\star=BB^\star$$

So. $BB^\star$ is Hermitian matrix.